# Association with scope in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Ruby on Rails application in which I have licenses, items that can be licensed and a table that lists the two (Which items in what quantity are present in the license?). Analogously to the items in a shopping cart.

Some of the items will no longer be marketed, but I intend to keep them in the database. I then created a *soft-delete* and used a default scope for the template and for the relationships. But when I try to change existing records using the related template, I get an exception: `ActiveRecord :: ReadOnlyRecord`

My templates look like this:

```
class Item <ActiveRecord :: Base
  default_scope {where (deleted: false)}
end

class LicenseItem <ActiveRecord :: Base
  belongs_to: license, touch: true
  belongs_to: item
end

class License <ActiveRecord :: Base
  has_many: license_items,
          -> {joins (: item) .where (items: {deleted: false})},
          dependent:: destroy
end
```

In this way:

```
pry (main)> License.find (0) .license_items [0] .readonly?
=> true
```

Is there any way to make this relationship not just reading?

I have already tried to add `readonly (false)` at the end of the `has_many` scope to`License` without success.

Comment: This may help you a little bit: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10615. In Rails 3.x, it looks like there was an implicit read-only when you use `joins`. In Rails 4 and beyond, that seems to have been removed. According to that issue though, `readonly(false)` is the recommended way. It's weird that it's not working for you.

Comment: For soft-delete  https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia gem provides handy functions .

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that gem :)

Answer (score 5):

According to [this thread in GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/11199), this is a Rails 4.0 bug, which has been fixed in version 4.0.1. Updating your Rails, you can include `readonly (false)` in your scope and it will work:

```
class License <ActiveRecord :: Base
    has_many: license_items,
          -> {joins (: item) .where (items: {deleted: false}). readonly (false)},
          dependent:: destroy
end
```

To update the Rails version, edit your `Gemfile` and then run`bundle update`.

In the latter case, if you can not update the Rails version, you can pass the `readonly: false` option to the`find` (not recommended) method:

```
License.find (1) .license_items.find (1, readonly: false) .update_attributes (amount: 5)
```